# In Perl, how can I generate random strings consisting of eight hex digits?

Tags: string, random, activeperl, perl

Using Perl, without using any extra modules that don't come with ActivePerl, how can I create a string of 8 characters from 0-F. example `0F1672DA`? The padding should be controllable and exactly 8 characters is preferable.

More examples of the kinds of strings I would like to generate:

```
28DA9782
55C7128A
```

Comment: Golf: `perl -e'print[0..9,A..F]->[rand 16]for 1..8'`

Comment: Why downvoting? I do need to learn programming. What is stackoverflow for if not these kind of questions?

Comment: I did not vote your post down. However, generally, ruling out any CPAN modules is not looked upon favorably. Also, you are expected to make some effort to come up with a solution of your own, and ask for help with that rather than expecting others to give you canned solutions.

Comment: CPAN is a pain on ActiveState. :) I recommend Strawberry Perl.

Comment: @Quentin - I did not have much problems with CPAN on AS perl. They ship C compiler and dmake via ppm (`ppm inst dmake`, `ppm inst mingw`). I prefer `cpanm` for installing modules directly from cpan (`ppm inst App::cpanminus`).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In principle, you ought to be able to do

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict; use warnings;

for (1 .. 10) {
    printf "%08X\n", rand(0xffffffff);
}
```

However, you may find out that —at least on some systems with some `perl`s (if not all)— the [range of `rand` is restricted to 32,768 values](http://blog.nu42.com/2010/09/be-vary-of-using-built-in-rng-for.html).

You can also study the source code of [String::Random](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/String::Random) to learn how to generate random strings satisfying other conditions.

However, my caution against using the built in `rand` on Windows system still stands. See [Math::Random::MT](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Math::Random::MT) for a high quality RNG.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict; use warnings;

my @set = ('0' ..'9', 'A' .. 'F');
my $str = join '' => map $set[rand @set], 1 .. 8;
print "$str\n";
```

PS: [The issue with Perl's rand on Windows was fixed in 5.20](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/RJBS/perl-5.20.0/pod/perldelta.pod#rand-now-uses-a-consistent-random-number-generator):

> This meant that the quality of perl's random numbers would vary from platform to platform, from the 15 bits of rand() on Windows to 48-bits on POSIX platforms such as Linux with drand48().
>
> Perl now uses its own internal drand48() implementation on all platforms. This does not make perl's rand cryptographically secure. [perl #115928]

Comment: Surely there is a plugin that comes with ActivePerl that overcomes the limit of `rand`?

Comment: Would a solution be using `rand` for 1 digit at a time? Does your second example do this?

Comment: Yes, the second method does generate the string one digit at a time using an adaptable `@set` similar to @Oleg's method (which I voted up).

Answer (score 12):

General example, allowing any range of characters:

```
my @chars = ('0'..'9', 'A'..'F');
my $len = 8;
my $string;
while($len--){ $string .= $chars[rand @chars] };
print "$string\n";
```

Answer (score 6):

Use [`sprintf`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html) to convert numbers to hex.

```
$foo .= sprintf("%x", rand 16) for 1..8;
```

Answer (score 5):

```
sprintf("%08X", rand(0xFFFFFFFF))
```

some people mentioned the windows-limit of rand with the MAX-Value of rand(0x7FFF) or rand(32768) decimal, i would overcome this with binary shifting-operator '<<'

```
# overcomes the windows-rand()-only-works-with-max-15bit-(32767)-limitation:
#   needed 8*4==32bit random-number:
#     first get the 15 high-significant bits shift them 17bits to the left,
#     then the next 15bits shifted 2 bits to the left,
#     then the last 2 bits with no shifting:
printf( '%08X', (
    (rand(0x8000)<<17) + (rand(0x8000)<<2) + rand(0b100) )
      );
```

But i consider this only as academic, because it is really awkward code which is difficult to understand.
I would not use this in real-life code, only if speed mater the most.
But maybe its the fastest solution and it's demonstrating a schema to overcome the limitation of the rand()-function under windows...

Comment: This won't work according to @Sinan. `rand`'s range is only to 32,768!

Comment: My statement was somewhat weaker: *On at least some Windows systems, `rand`'s range might be limited to 32,768 values.

Comment: I think Sinan Ünür should file a bug-report, if this is really true. And rand() returning values are in the set of only 32768 different numbers. perldoc -f tells me rand should return a fractional number. I think my solution is correct according to the documentation, and my own test.

Comment: Why can't you file a bug report? :)

Comment: I can't reproduce this error. I don't like Win :). Once i found a bug but it was gone after updating Perl ... i was to late.

Comment: @LutzL. I am going by the words of Sinan, and frankly, based on ActiveState's behavior under Windows, I believe him. How can you work under Linux, u must have poor hardware (or a supercomputer ;) ).

Comment: @Sinan: I think its a bug, and worth to trace it. Just run %h=map{ rand()=>´´ } 1..1_000_000; print 0+keys(%h); and please report it, this will help to build a reliable perl on windows.

Comment: Lutz and @briandfoy The issue is with the [`rand` implementation that comes with Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/398ax69y%28v=vs.80%29.aspx): *The rand function returns a pseudorandom integer in the range 0 to `RAND_MAX` (`32767`)* It's a platform limitation. Even if some build of `perl` some time in the future changed to some other `rand`, the principle would remain: If you care about what `rand` produces, then use something that has defined good properties.

Answer (score 1):

From the "golf" comment by *daxim*:

```
perl -e'print[0..9,A..F]->[rand 16]for 1..8'
```